# Jenkins Git Branch not working with Environment Variables

Tags: jenkins

Folks,
  There is an environment variable a job is configured with, `BRANCH`, but when I try configuring git scm with it, i get an error in console

`Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')` */${BRANCH}

> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/${BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/${BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse origin/${BRANCH}^{commit} # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build.

I am 100% certain git is fine, branch exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*/${BRANCH}` to `*/$BRANCH`, this works for me.

**Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')**  `*/$BRANCH`

Comment: @chrmod were you using pipelines, or just plain-old Jenkins? I got the same issue as you today, but only when using pipelines.

Comment: @thiagowfx I think this issue is resolved in Pipelines these days. You can try to update pipeline plugins.

Comment: In Pipelines, make sure you aren't specifying a Lightweight Checkout. As of Jenkins 2.73, Lightweight Checkouts will not read the environment variable, but a full checkout will.

Answer (score 25):

So under full checkout , Change */${BRANCH} to */$BRANCH, this should read the environment variable.

Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')  */$BRANCH

In Pipelines, make sure you aren't specifying a Lightweight Checkout. As of Jenkins 2.73, Lightweight Checkouts will not read the environment variable, but a full checkout will

Check this issue discussion for more details https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/564

Comment: Yes, I think untick `Lightweight Checkout` fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to keep the curly brackets `${BRANCH}`. The fix for me was indeed to uncheck `Lightweight Checkout`

Comment: This is not working for me :
 `> git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/$BRANCH^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "origin/$BRANCH^{commit}" # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`
I'm using BitBucket and don't have an option for 'lightweight checkout'

Comment: @SimonStorr keep the curly brackets, i.e., use ${BRANCH} not $BRANCH. Not sure why some answers are saying get rid of those.