# Jenkins parameterized build: build fails due to git parameter includes {^commit}

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to set up a parameterized build so the user can select branch and then  press "build" to build that branch.

In configure I have added a git parameter "branch", like this:
[image]

I have then added the "branch" parameter as branch specifier in the pipeline definition like this:
[image]

When I start the build, I can select the branch without a problem. In this example /origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1. 
But the build will fail with the following console output:

> Started by user xxxx Lightweight checkout support not available,
>   falling back to full checkout. Checking out git
>   ssh://gitolite@tuleap.ermms.se/ermms/acm.git into
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6smCustomBuild@script to read
>   ci/jenkins/6msBuildAndTest.groovy
>
> > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   
>    > git config remote.origin.url ssh://gitolite@tuleap.ermms.se/ermms/acm.git # timeout=10 Fetching
>   upstream changes from ssh://gitolite@tuleap.ermms.se/ermms/acm.git
>   
>    > git --version # timeout=10 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
>   
>    > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://gitolite@tuleap.ermms.se/ermms/acm.git
>   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   
>    > git rev-parse /origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1^{commit} # timeout=10
>   
>    > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin//origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1^{commit} #
>   timeout=10
>   
>   > git rev-parse /origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1^{commit} # timeout=10
>
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and
>   branch configuration for this job. 
>   
>   ERROR: Maximum checkout retry
>   attempts reached, aborting Finished: FAILURE

So Jenkins can not find the branch /origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1 because he is searching for /origin/feature/kvarntorp-test1^{commit}

Where did ^{commit} come from? Can I somehow remove the ^{commit} in the build configuration?
Have I configured the build wrong?

I have tried different names instead of "branch". [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo) suggests I should use sha1 with the default value "master". I tried sha1 as Git Parameter Name and ${sha1} as Branch Specifier. The build failed with the following console output:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${sha1}:refs/remotes/origin/${sha1} --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${sha1}
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:405)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:351)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:196)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:298)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git PullRequest job failed. Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906352/git-pullrequest-job-failed-couldnt-find-any-revision-to-build-verify-the-repo)

Comment: No, parameter name sha1 does not help.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working. It was a combination of two things.
First, I hade to uncheck Lightweight checkout as described in [Jenkins Git Branch not working with Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928873/jenkins-git-branch-not-working-with-environment-variables#30423200).

But that alone did not solve it. I also had to set the parameter name to sha1 and the branch specifier to ${sha1}.

Comment: This answer was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

From `SCM/Branches to build's` manual:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a
>   repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes
>   and built.
>
> The safest way is to use the refs/heads/ syntax. This way
>   the expected branch is unambiguous.
>
> If your branch name has a / in it make sure to use the full reference
>   above. When not presented with a full path the plugin will only use
>   the part of the string right of the last slash. Meaning foo/bar will
>   actually match bar
>   If you use a wildcard branch specifier, with a slash (e.g. release/),
>   you'll need to specify the origin repository in the branch names to
>   make sure changes are picked up. So e.g. origin/release/
>
> Possible options:
>
> Tracks/checks out the specified branch. If ambiguous the
>   first result is taken, which is not necessarily the expected one.
>   Better use refs/heads/. E.g. master, feature1,...

So try refs/heads/${branch}

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I got:hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${branch}:refs/remotes/origin/${branch} --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${branch}